# Before every GWT RPC method call -> execute some check and throw a checked exception

Tags: java, exception, servlets, gwt, signature

I have all the logic in place to check if a user is logged in and therefore is allowed to execute a RPC call. I can place this check in all my RPC methods and throw a `throw new MyLoginException()` if the user is not logged in. In the client side I just check for this exception and handle it accordingly.

The problem now is: I don't want to put this in every RPC method. I want a generic solution for this.

I tried to override methods like `com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall()` which is called before every RPC call. Problem here: I can only throw unchecked exception because the method signature  does not allow me to throw my own exception. The unchecked exception result then in generic exception in the client code and I can not handle them correctly because I do not know anymore which exception was thrown.

Where can I put my login check? Is there any clean solution for this problem?

Comment: You could do something like [this](http://www.objectpartners.com/2013/04/04/improving-the-gwt-async-callback/).

Comment: @Baz I have something like this. But this does not help me since this is only on the client side. If I throw an unchecked exception on the backend, I just receive an generic error on the client side and can not determine what went wrong there.

Comment: I don't seem to understand. Why can you only throw an unchecked exception from the server?

Comment: I can throw throw a checked exception as well - in theory. But: I have to do it some method, that is called every time a RPC call is executed. As an example I mentioned "RemoteServiceServlet.processCall()": I can override it but I then can not change the signature. And the signature only defines a "SerialisationException" in this case.

Comment: If you use the approach described in the link, you can use this new callback for all your RPCs and still throw checked exceptions whenever necessary. That's what I do here myself (not exactly the same but similar).

Comment: The client side is fine. But I am looking for a place at the server side, where I could hook in my check and throw the exception. And the hook needs to be executed before any rpc call is invoked (but on the server side)

Comment: Ah, I see. Let me check if I can find something

Comment: Found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/D2MPaD2EpOQ). Not sure if it'll do what you want. (If you do eventually find a solution, please come back and post it. I (and possibly others) would be very interested to see a solution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution in the link posted by Baz: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/D2MPaD2EpOQ

Instead of throwing the exception like this (Which is not possible since the signature only allows `SerializationException` :

```
@Override
public String processCall(String payload) throws SerializationException {

    if(!userIsAuthorized()){
        throw new MyAuthorizationException();
    }

    return super.processCall(payload);
}
```

The exception has to be returned encoded in the response like this:

```
@Override
public String processCall(String payload) throws SerializationException {

    if(!userIsAuthorized()){
        return RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(null, new MyAuthorizationException());
    }

    return super.processCall(payload);
}
```

This will be called every time a RPC call is invoked and the method will not be executed if the user is not authorized and the checked exception will be transported to the front end where it can be handled accordingly.

**Edit** @Baz: This is how the client handling looks like for me. But I think if you get a IncompatibleRemoteServiceException you have a problem that some old stuff is cached in your browser und you need to clean your cache.

```
@Override
public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
    try {
        throw caught;
    }
        catch (SessionExpiredException ex){
            onSessionExpired();
    }catch(Throwable e){
        MyCallback.this.onFailure(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you handle/catch the exception on the client? I seem to receive a `IncompatibleRemoteServiceException` that somehow contains my actual exception.

Comment: Yeah, it's weird. You should be able to do `caught instanceof SessionExpiredException` though. Don't know why I get the other exception. Cleared the cache and everything... My actual exception is hidden in there somewhere, so I'll use a workaround for now. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: @Baz It is because the method you are trying to call does not throw the exception you actually throwing from processCall(String) method.